# moving human 3d model that was made in blender/sculptrist in java

Tags: java, programming-languages, game-engine

I was doing a human 3d model in sculptris and blender and i wanna ask how do programmers make the 3d model run/move with in the java or other programming langauges. do they do it within the programming language or do they do it on a certain program and then put it in the programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tough to answer because how to show, move and animate a model in java can differ on many different things.

The first you need to do is pick a library such as jogl or lwjgl. These are opengl bindings for java and allow for 3d graphics.

Then you will need to learn the basics of how to create a simple application using the library you have chosen.

Then learn how to read your model, load a texture and apply it. This will differ depending on what the texture and model formats are.

There's no one tutorial to show you all of this but you can look at the playlist I have linked which should help you get started assuming you know basic game programming concepts and java programming.

You could look here at [Coding Universe](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL19F2453814E0E315). It would be the best place to get started.